# Problem with regexp in userscript for chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

This might be a noob question, but I have tried to find an answere here and on other sites and I have still not find the answere. At least not so that I understand enough to fix the problem.

This is used in a userscript for chrome.

I'm trying to select a date from a string. The string is the innerHTML from a tag that I have managed to select. The html structure, and also the string, is something like this: (the div is the selected tag so everything within is the content of the string)

```
<div id="the_selected_tag">  
    <a href="http://www.something.com"  title="something xxx">link</a>  
    " 2011-02-18 23:02"  
    <a href="http://www.somthingelse.com" title="another link">thing</a>
</div>
```

If you have a solution that helps me select the date without this fuzz, it would also be great.

The javascript:

```
var pattern = /\"\s[\d\s:-]*\"/i;
var tag = document.querySelector('div.the_selected_tag');
var date_str = tag.innerHTML.match(pattern)[0]
```

When I use this script as ordinary javascript on a html document to test it, it works perfectly, but when I install it as a userscript in chrome, it doesn't find the pattern.

I can't figure out how to get around this problem.

Comment: Your regex looks mostly okay to me, although you could try replacing the `*` with a `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump innerHTML into console. If it looks fine then start building regexp from more generic (`/\d+/`) to more specific ones and output everything into a console. There is a bunch of different quote characters in different encodings, many different types of dashes.

`[\d\s:-]*` is not a very good choice because it would match `" 1"`, `" "`. I would rather write something as specific as possible:

```
/" \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}"/
```

(Also `document.querySelector('div.the_selected_tag')` would return null on your sample but you probably wanted to write `class` instead of `id`)

Comment: Probably better to use: `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}/` (Lose the bracketing quotes and space(s), since these are superfluous and may not be what they appear to be (*&quot;*, etc.).

Comment: I wanted to write it as easy as possible iwthout having to spell everything out, but I guess it would have been the best solution. The " characters disappeared from the innerHTML, thats why it didn't work. I will implement your solution since it seems to be the most water proof one.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's much more likely that tag.innerHTML doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: I've tested the content of course, so yes, it does contain what I think it contains. Also, this code does work when I make my own html-page with this javascript inserted.

Comment: Actually, you where right. For some reason the " disappeared when I selected innerHTML this way. It didn't earlier, thats why I was so sure of it. My own copy of the html still had the "-characters, so thats why it worked in my testing environment. Thanks for your help.